# Find all $\lambda > 0$ so that $y^{(4)} - \lambda y = 0$ has non-trivial solutions

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

**Question:**

Find all $\lambda > 0$ for which the problem:

$$y^{(4)} - \lambda y = 0$$

with the initial conditions:

$$y(0) = y(\pi) = y''(0) = y''(\pi) = 0$$

has a non-trivial solution.

**Attempted solution:**

The characteristic equation is:

$$r^4 - \lambda = (r+\sqrt[4]{\lambda})(r-\sqrt[4]{\lambda})(r+i\sqrt[4]{\lambda} (r-i\sqrt[4]{\lambda})$$

The solution becomes:

$$y = C_1e^{-\sqrt[4]{\lambda}x}+C_2e^{\sqrt[4]{\lambda}x} + A\cos \sqrt[4]{\lambda}x + B\sin \sqrt[4]{\lambda}x$$

Left is to determine the four unknowns. Luckily, we have four initial conditions, so this should work.

Taking the derivative twice:

$$y'' = \sqrt{\lambda}C_1e^{-\sqrt[4]{\lambda}x}+\sqrt{\lambda}C_2e^{\sqrt[4]{\lambda}x} - \sqrt{\lambda}A\sin \sqrt[4]{\lambda}x + \sqrt{\lambda}B\cos \sqrt[4]{\lambda}x$$

The four initial conditions:

$$y(0) = C_1 + C_2 + A = 0$$
$$y''(0) = \sqrt{\lambda}C_1 + \sqrt{\lambda}C_2 + \sqrt{\lambda}B = 0 $$
$$y(\pi) = C_1e^{-\sqrt[4]{\lambda}\pi}+C_2e^{\sqrt[4]{\lambda}\pi} + A\cos \sqrt[4]{\lambda}\pi + B\sin \sqrt[4]{\lambda}\pi = 0$$
$$y''(\pi) = \sqrt{\lambda}C_1e^{-\sqrt[4]{\lambda}\pi}+\sqrt{\lambda}C_2e^{\sqrt[4]{\lambda}\pi} - \sqrt{\lambda}A\sin \sqrt[4]{\lambda}\pi + \sqrt{\lambda}B\cos \sqrt[4]{\lambda}\pi = 0$$

However, the last two initial conditions seem very complex and do not seem to easily reduce to something I can use to figure out the value of the four constants.

How can this question be finished off?

The expected answer is:

$$\lambda = n^4, n = 1,2,...$$

The corresponding solutions are:

$$y = D\sin nx$$

Comment: Your second derivative is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second derivative is 
$$
y'' = \sqrt{\lambda}C_1e^{-\sqrt[4]{\lambda}x}+\sqrt{\lambda}C_2e^{\sqrt[4]{\lambda}x} - \sqrt{\lambda}A\cos \sqrt[4]{\lambda}x - \sqrt{\lambda}B\sin \sqrt[4]{\lambda}x.
$$
This makes your second condition 
$$
C_1+C_2-A=0. 
$$
Together with the first one, you get $A=0$, and $C_2=-C_1$.  Now the third and fourth conditions become 
$$
0=-2C_1\sinh\lambda^{1/4}\pi+B\sin\lambda^{1/4}\pi,\ \ \ \ 0=-2C_1\sinh\lambda^{1/4}\pi-B\sin\lambda^{1/4}\pi.
$$
So $B\sin\lambda^{1/4}\pi=0$. If $B=0$, as $\sinh \lambda^{1/4}\pi\neq0$, we get the solution $y=0$.

When $B\ne0$, we have $\sin\lambda^{1/4}\pi=0$; this forces $\lambda^{1/4}=n$, so $\lambda=n^4$, and 
$$
y(x)=\sin n^4x,\ \ n\in\mathbb N. 
$$

Comment: When I try to do the $y(\pi) = 0$ case, I get $y(\pi) = C_1e^{(-\sqrt[4]{\lambda})x} - C_1e^{(\sqrt[4]{\lambda})x} + 0 + B\sin \sqrt[4]{\lambda}x$ Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I had a typo. I just wrote $2\sinh z$ instead of $e^z-e^{-z}$.

Comment: Oh, it was my fault. I did not see the h part of sinh. Thanks.

Comment: No no, I just edited the h in a few seconds ago.

Comment: Are you sure the solution $y = 0$ should be inferred from $\lambda = 0$ and not from visual inspection of the equation? The question specifies $\lambda > 0$...

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have rephrased that sentence.